# Как вывести все числа (1 до 99), которые делятся на введенное число без остатка?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int N, i;
    cin >> N;
    for (N <= 99; i = ++N;) {
        if (i % N == 0) {
            cout << N << endl;
        }
            
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Было много попыток решить эту задачу, но всегда что-то не получалось. Подскажите как ее решить, хотя-бы совет, чтоб идти в верном направлении. Как я понял, в этой задаче обязательно нужны условия, но какой именной цикл выбрать, так и не понял.

Comment: Замените цикл на `for (int i = 1; i <= 99; i++)` и читайте учебники...

Comment: @Harry Спасибо большое за совет.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int N, i;
    cin >> N;
    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        if (i % N == 0) {
            cout << N << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: условие `i <= 99`